# TimescaleDB/Postgres: INSERT ON CONFLICT KEEP MAXIMUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

My table is defined as: (it is a simple metric-config tracking one)

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strategy_registry (
        name            VARCHAR     NOT NULL,
        symbol          VARCHAR     NOT NULL,
        predictor_id    VARCHAR     NOT NULL,
        params          jsonb       NOT NULL,
        metric          FLOAT       NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(name, symbol, predictor_id)
        );
```

And on insert conflict, I want to keep the maximum metric and the params column, of the version that got the maximum metric value. I am using TimescaleDB (postgres 12)

```
    INSERT INTO strategy_registry (name, symbol, predictor_id, params, metric)
    VALUES ({{ name }}, {{ symbol }}, {{ predictor_id }}, {{ params }}, {{ metric }})
    ON CONFLICT (name, symbol, predictor_id) 
    DO UPDATE SET 
    (metric, params) = max(existing, excluded), params of greatest `metric` column value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can handle both columns at the same time.  Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO strategy_registry (name, symbol, predictor_id, params, metric)
VALUES ({{ name }}, {{ symbol }}, {{ predictor_id }}, {{ params }}, {{ metric }})
  ON CONFLICT (name, symbol, predictor_id) 
    DO UPDATE 
      SET params = CASE 
                     WHEN metric < EXCLUDED.metric THEN EXCLUDED.params
                     ELSE params
                   END,
          metric = GREATEST(metric, EXCLUDED.metric);
```

Comment: The where clause in the update can handle both columns at once.

Answer (score 4):

The function you looking for is **greatest(...)** not max. Max is a columnar function that works on the entire set of rows, in this case in the table. Greatest chooses the 'maximum' value from a list of values (or variables). Example:

```
select greatest(1,4,3,5,7,0)
```

returns 7. It is also usable in an assignment as

```
something = greatest(...);
```

Comment: You do not handle both cases. I do not know why you've got 4 upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers should work, however, I would say that it is probably not the most efficient way to achieve this. Instead I would use the `WHERE` clause in the update:

```
ON CONFLICT (name, symbol, predictor_id)  DO UPDATE SET
metric = excluded.metric, params = excluded.params
WHERE excluded.metric > metric
```

The previous answer can do the update even when the value stays the same and cause table bloat and extra work (also, I think it's clearer semantically).